# Check if NSArray contains object with specific property

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, nsarray, time-complexity

I have an array of UIView. I want to check if that array contains UIView with specific tag. If it does then I should get that view or else I should receive nil.

As of now I using following

```
// validCells is an array UIView

NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id obj, NSDictionary *ignored){
            return ((UIView *)obj).tag == i;
        }];

UIView *cell = [[validCells filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p] lastObject];
```

This works fine but complexity is n^2. I was wondering if there is any other better way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a particular need to use a predicate? You can do it in O(n) just by enumerating. Also, is this really too slow? How many views can you possibly have?

Comment: Why is complexity n^2?

Comment: Why do you think the complexity is O(n^2) ?

Comment: C. A. R. Hoare: 
"Premature optimization is the root of all evil in programming. "

Comment: @JoshCaswell: At max I can have about 35- 40 UIViews in that array. I know it wont matter for that small number of elements.@zaph: I was just looking for better way of doing it because I don't feel what I have done is correct.

Comment: Probably, creating an extra array every time you want to access one view is not good way to implement. Thanks @MartinR for pointing it out.

Comment: @Sumit Your method is fine as is Martin's. From my perspective I would choose the one that is most intuitive, write for the human reader, not the compiler.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't think the complexity of your method is O(n^2), it is more probably like O(n).
But there is no reason to create a temporary array if you just search for a specific
element. As @Josh said, you can do a simple enumeration.

If you want to be a bit more fancy, you can write it as

```
NSUInteger index = [validCells indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(UIView *view, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return view.tag == idx;
}];
if (index != NSNotFound) {
    cell = validCells[index];
}
```